# BIgquery: How do I schedule a query to append an existing table with a new table?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, scheduled-tasks

I am new to Biguery and I need to understand the functions on how to create automation within the system. My task is to create a near real-time dynamic dashboard of my company's sales data from Google Cloud Storage to BigQuery to Google Data Studio. I want to be sure I create one truth of data that will continuously be updated with current sales data moving forward rather than having to generate a new table from which to do data analysis on.

1. I have my datasets exported from our POS, and uploaded files to GCS in a bucket. This will occur on a weekly basis pulling sales data from the previous week.
2. In Bigquery, I provide that dataset from GCS to create a table according to its time period (For example, Oct_Wk2_2022).
3. With my limited background in SQL, I created a saved query where I made a UNION for each table to save the query as a new table. Here's a snippet of the SQL:

   SELECT
   Date, Time, Category, Item, Qty, Price_Point_Name, SKU, Modifiers_Applied, Gross_Sales, Discounts, Net_Sales, Tax, Location, Customer_Name
   FROM
   `store-sales-daily-item-summary.Square_Sales_2022.Oct_Wk2_2022`
   UNION ALL
   SELECT
   Date, Time, Category, Item, Qty, Price_Point_Name, SKU, Modifiers_Applied, Gross_Sales, Discounts, Net_Sales, Tax, Location, Customer_Name
   FROM
   `store-sales-daily-item-summary.Square_Sales_2022.Oct_Wk1_2022`

When I export to BigQuery Table, it asks for a Destination table - from here, I can't add to an existing table (created from a previous BigQuery).

How do I create a scheduled query in SQL to append an existing table when I add a new table into BigQuery? What should my query look like to make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

`merge` from the data manipulation language will do the trick of updating your existing table with least effort.
You can also handle duplicates with `merge` across the existing and new data.

next you can schedule the `merge` query.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#update_statement

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/dml-syntax#merge_statement

Comment: I was able to successfully create a merge of the data set. What I have been doing is that as I received new sales data, I would run the Merge query again, except replace the 2nd line with the new sales data to add to the existing.